# Insert document in MongoDB using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm using Python for the first time to run a crawler. I've got the crawler to work and now I want to save the results in my MongoDB using pymongo,but for some reason I get this error: "NameError: name 'city' is not defined". If I wrap city in quotes,it works as expected,but I want to save it as it is. Anyone has done something similar or know what the solution is?

```
def gotHolidays(self, response):
        cityName = response.meta['name']
        feriado = []
        facult = []
        for selector in response.css("span.one"):
            feriado.append(selector.css("::text").extract())

        for selector in response.css("span.two"):
            facult.append(selector.css("::text").extract())

        city = {
            'city': cityName,
            'holidays':{
                'facult': facult,
                'feriado': feriado                
            }
        }
        print(json.dumps(city))

    from pymongo import MongoClient
    client = MongoClient()
    client = MongoClient ('localhost', 27017)
    db = client['myBank']
    myCollection = db.myCollection
    myCollection_data = {
        'cities': city
    }
    result = myCollection.insert_one (myCollection_data)
```

Comment: In which line are you getting the error?

Comment: 'cities': city. It says the name city is not defined

Comment: You seem to have a scope problem: `issue` is a dictionary that cannot be accessed outside of the `gotHolidays()` method. 
Or maybe it is just a formatting problem on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation looks wrong in your code snippet. 
The line `from pymongo import ...` should be at the same indentation level as the previous line:

```
        print(json.dumps(city))

        from pymongo import MongoClient
        client = MongoClient()
```

For python, indentation defines the scope. Un-indenting code is interpreted by python as 'end of the function'. Therefore, when you try to access the 'city' variable, it is no longer in scope